# Android action bar / navigation bar

Tags: android

Somewhere guidelines are what size should be "action bar" and "navigation bar"? I found only guidelines for icons.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [Metrics and Grids](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html#examples).

It lists the approximate size in dp for both ActionBar and navigation bar.